# Way to catch a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when loading a file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, icloud

I am using UIDocument to load files. I have now corrupted a file to see what happens and how my app behaves. It will crash with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and I was now wondering how I should handle such scenarios. Do I just *hope* that the file will never get corrupted? In pre-UIDocument days, I used @try and @catch for NSEXCEPTION, but this won't work with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Is this a case where I would use NSZOMBIE? As far as I understand the other posts, NSZombie is only used for debugging purposes and not really something you should always rely on. Here is the line of code which throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS if I corrupt my data:

```
 -(BOOL)loadFromContents:(id)contents ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {

if (!_books) {
        _books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

        self.books = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:contents]; // THIS WILL CRASH IF CONTENTS GOT CORRUPTED

        if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(libraryDocumentUpdated:)]) {
            [_delegate libraryDocumentUpdated:self];
        }

        return YES;
    }
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  loadFromContents is passing an invalid contents object so the unarchive crashes.  Clearly, to me, the bug is in iCloud, it should never pass invalid objects, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

An EXEC_BAD_ACCESS is not an exception that you catch, its telling you that you are accessing an invalid memory address, resulting in a crash. NSZombies is just a way of keeping all the objects that should have been deallocated "alive" (therefore not freeing the memory they occupy, which is not what you want in a release build obviously) so as to tell you which "deallocated" you are messaging. You need to work out why you are getting the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. Is books a retained property?

Comment: Yes, it is: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *books; However, I don't understand why I'm only getting this if I corrupt the data? I have another line of code which I omitted in the sample above. I just added it - perhaps that would be the reason. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, in the main file I have : @synthesize books = _books; That's basically it.

Comment: You shouldn't have this line _books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; (it should be self.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]) and you are reassigning it with the unarchive anyway so it serves no purpose.

Comment: `self.prop = [[Somthing alloc] init]` is a memory leak unless we're talking about ARC  @jbat

Comment: I see. I removed the line, but it still crashes. Books is not mentioned anywhere else in this part of the code (which is called at the very beginning). It's very strange as this will only happen with a corrupted file. Perhaps it has something to do with the unarchiving which will certainly be messed up in this case? Also, you asked if books is a retained property - as it is, what difference does this make? Thanks.

Comment: I think he was using ARC as he is declaring @property (nonatomic, strong).

Comment: Actually, no, I'm not using ARC. Is this the solution? I just copied sample code from apple (hence the nonatomic, strong). Perhaps strong is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should find out the root cause of the crash and fix it. If you really want to catch EXC_BAD_ACCESS, you can.
A new C library [SignalRecovery](https://github.com/dhatbj/SignalRecovery) can enable programs to recover from operating system exceptions such as EXC_BAD_ACCESS. It can be used in iOS/macOS/Linux.
Sample code:

```
signal_try(label) {
    // Add your code need try.
    int* ptr = NULL;
    *ptr = 0;
}
signal_catch(label) {
    // Add your code to process exceptions, or do nothing.
    siginfo_t* info = signal_info();
}
signal_end(label)
// Continue run
```